# Не могу выбрать элемент JS

Tags: javascript, html

Есть div class="top", выбираю в нём строку пустой таблицы с помощью document.querySelector(...); и вывожу в консоль и выводится как на картинке. Есть точно такой же div class="left" с пустой таблицей и с ним всё в порядке.
вот селекторы

```
var top = document.querySelector("div.top > table > tr");
var left = document.querySelector(".left > table");
```

вот HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>
        введите количество городов: <input type="number" min="0" max="100" id="countOfCity">  
   </p>

   <div id="message"></div>

   <div class="top"><table><tr></tr></table></div>

   <div class="left"><table></table></div>

    <table>
        <tbody id="makeTable">
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="interface">
        <button onclick="makeArr()">создать массив</button>  
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выбрать этот элемент? Даже если использовать сгенерированный хромом селектор не работает.

Comment: @РустамГимранов я неправильно выразился, мне нужна строка пустой таблицы в div.top, да и если сам div выбирать то же самое будет

Comment: В актуальном DOM строки могут быть вложены в tbody даже если их не было в HTML.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы злоупотребляете оператором "непосредственный потомок"(`>`)

Comment: @vp_arth ни один из этих
var top = document.querySelector("div.top > table > tbody > tr")
var top = document.querySelector("div.top table tr")
селекторов не работает, всё то же выдаёт

Comment: В моём ответе есть сниппет, который выдаёт искомую строку в консоль. У вас какой браузер?

Comment: @vp_arth хром .

Comment: А где вы пишете javascript код? Он должен быть после искомых элементов, желательно перед закрывающим тегом </body>

Comment: @vp_arth у меня стоит атрибут defer у тега подключения скрипта, сейчас перенёс его перед закрывающим тегом </body> и ничего не изменилось

Comment: Посмотрите `console.log(document.body.innerHTML)`

Comment: @vp_arth выводит HTML код страницы, в нём есть div.top

Comment: Прискорбно, у вас что-то сломалось)

Comment: @vp_arth в CSS мой селектор кстати работает, и если в console.log указать не переменную а её содержимое то тоже нормально выводит

Comment: Что значит "не переменную, а её содержимое"? Попробуйте переименовать переменную/

Comment: @vp_arth значит не conosle.log(top) а  conosle.log(document.querySelector(".top > table > tbody > tr")) а

Answer (score 1):

> В актуальном DOM строки могут быть вложены в tbody даже если их не было в HTML

Продемонстрирую:

```js
let topTr = document.querySelector('.top > table > tbody > tr')

console.log(topTr)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script defer src="map.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    введите количество городов: <input type="number" min="0" max="100" id="countOfCity">
  </p>

  <div id="message"></div>

  <div class="top">
    <table>
      <tr></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="left">
    <table></table>
  </div>

  <table>
    <tbody id="makeTable">
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="interface">
    <button onclick="makeArr()">создать массив</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `top` в глобальном контексте зарезервирована под "самое родительское" окно.
Либо перенесите код в функцию, либо переименуйте переменную.

[Window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/top)

Также можете воспользоваться переменными блочной видимости:

```
{// Фигурные скобки важны - они формируют область видимости для let/const
  let top = document.querySelector(selector);
  console.log(top);
}
```

Comment: можно без фигурных скобок

Comment: Можно. но зачем гадить в родительский scope?

Comment: ну, деланье отдельных блоков тоже загаживает родительский скоп, просто с другой стороны :)

Answer (score -1):

Нужно было сменить имя переменной с top на что нибудь другое.